# OpenGL Depth Not working, Triangles Disappear

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

For some reason I can't detect I can't set a z index for any triangle. The triangle will display, at the same depth, from 1 to -1 (inclusive), but after that it dissapers. I am not applying any MVP matrix (trying to figure out this first) and I would expect to be able to see my triangle get smaller as I decrease the z value. This is what I have so far:

```
//My main function
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA|GLUT_ALPHA|GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_DEPTH);
glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
glutCreateWindow("Window");

if (init_resources()) {
    glutDisplayFunc(onDisplay);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutMainLoop();
}

//And in my display function
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT| GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

And with my vertext shader:

```
gl_Position = vec4(coord2d, 0.0, 1.0);
```

`glGetIntegerv(GL_DEPTH_BITS, &depth)` also returns 24.

edit: full code

```
Sprite *sprite1;
Sprite *sprite2;

GLuint program;
GLuint cameraAttribute;

int init_resources()
{   

    //Link shaders, create program and attach shaders
    GLint link_ok = GL_FALSE;
    GLuint vs, fs;
    if ((vs = create_shader("vertShader.sh", GL_VERTEX_SHADER))   == 0) return 0;
    if ((fs = create_shader("fragShader.sh", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)) == 0) return 0;

    program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);


    glLinkProgram(program);
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &link_ok);
    if (!link_ok) {
        fprintf(stderr, "glLinkProgram:");
        print_log(program);
        return 0;
    }

    //Create Attributes
    cameraAttribute = glGetUniformLocation(program, "camera");
    if(cameraAttribute == -1){
        cout << "Error!";
    }


    //Init sprites
    sprite1 = new Sprite();
    sprite2 = new Sprite();


    return 1;
}

void onDisplay()
{
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT| GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glUseProgram(program);


    sprite1->render();
    sprite2->render();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void idle()
{

    //Create Projection Matrix to change clip space.
    mat4 projectionMatrix = perspective(60.0f, (float)glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH) / (float)glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT), 0.1f, 100.f);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(cameraAttribute, 1, GL_FALSE, &projectionMatrix[0][0]);

}

void free_resources()
{
    glDeleteProgram(program);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA|GLUT_ALPHA|GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutCreateWindow("My Second Triangle");
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    if (init_resources()) {
        glutDisplayFunc(onDisplay);
        glutIdleFunc(idle);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        //uses glGetError to check for how many errors there are.
        cout << CheckGLErrors() << "\n";

        glutMainLoop();
    }


    free_resources();
    return 0;
}
```

And my sprite file:

```
#include "Sprite.h"

Sprite::Sprite(){
    init();
}


void Sprite::init(){

    GLfloat triangle_vertices[] = {
        0.0,  0.8f,
        -0.8f, -0.8f,
        0.8f, -0.8f,
    };

    //Set attributes
    locationAttribute = glGetAttribLocation(program, "coord2d");
    if (locationAttribute == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind attribute location");
    }

    translationUniform = glGetUniformLocation(program, "translationUniform");
    if(translationUniform == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind attribute transformation");
    }


    //Create buffer
    glGenBuffers(1, &mainBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mainBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangle_vertices), triangle_vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(
                          locationAttribute, // attribute
                          2,                 // number of elements per vertex, here (x,y)
                          GL_FLOAT,          // the type of each element
                          GL_FALSE,          // take our values as-is
                          0,                 // no extra data between each position
                          0                  // offset of first element
    );

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

void Sprite::render(){
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mainBuffer);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

}
```

And Vertex shader: (note, versions are added by the parser)

```
attribute vec2 coord2d;

uniform mat4 translationUniform;
uniform mat4 camera;


void main(void) {

    gl_Position = camera * vec4(coord2d, -1.1, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glEnable(GL_BLEND | GL_DEPTH_TEST);`

You can't combine these like this, you have to issue two glEnable commands. This is probably generating an error, or enabling something completely different.

You're confusing this with glClear, which uses bitwise masks.

Start using `glGetError` in your code, it would have caught this problem for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I only tried this out of desperation. It doesn't work with two separate statements either.

Comment: Hmm that's strange it's not an error. The bitwise or of GL_BLEND and GL_DEPTH_TEST is 0xBF3, which is not any opengl legal value that I can see. Anyway I think I found something else unrelated, I posted it in a separate post. @bipolarpants

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I reread the question, I think I understand now.

The triangle dissappears outside of -1 to 1, because without any projection matrix, you're drawing in normalized device coordinates, which has a near and far clip plane of -1 to 1. That means any vertex with a z value outside of -1 to 1 will be culled.

Secondly, you say that you don't see it getting smaller with distance. This is a feature of perspective projection, which you don't have (because you have no projection matrix). With a default projection matrix (orthographic), you will not get any perspective foreshortening, so your triangle will appear the same size regardless of distance. If you want to apply perspective to your scene, then you need a perspective matrix: try applying `gluPerspective(1, 45, 0.1, 100);` and this should give you something more like what you expect (triangle will appear with z from -0.1 to -100, getting smaller as it approaches z=-100). You may need to adjust these to match the scale of your scene.

Comment: Ok, so originally I had thought that may be the case. But when I tried then I used applied a transformation (created by GLMs perspective()) in a vertex shader and it had no effect. I also just tried `gluPerspective(1, 45, 0.1, 100);` in my onDisplay() function right before I swapped buffers and it also had no effect. ie, changing the FoV didn't do anything and the clipping planes were not affected.

Comment: @bipolarpants Post your full code please, I can't tell what's going on from those small snippets.

Comment: I believe that's everything, sorry if any of it is unclear/wrong as you can tell I'm new to OpenGL (and only mediocre C++)

Comment: Being wrong is fine, everybody is new sometime, but that code looks a mess. There's tons of unused code everywhere and I can't follow what you're trying to do. translationUniform is not used in the shader. You generate PV matrix and then ignore it. Maybe start by cleaning it up so that you're actually using the variables you generate, maybe you'll solve it yourself in the process. @bipolarpants

Comment: @bipolarpants: Also, you're setting '3' as the size of glVertexAttribPointer which should be '2', and you're setting matrix element 3-3 in sprite::move, it should be 4-3 (translation is in the last column). gluPerspective only effects the builtin matrix stack, and has no effect if you're using your own glm matrices.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 3-3? Because 0,1,2,3 so the third is actually the 4th? I could be completely wrong. Also the reason it's such a mess is because I've just been stripping out parts trying to figure out where I'm going wrong with this Depth, though I'll clean it up as best as possible.

Comment: @bipolarpants: Sorry, you're correct (spaced out for a second and I just read it as 3-3). I'm used to accessing elements as [0-15].

Comment: Ok, I clean it up as best I could. Removed unneeded code, added comments, and fixed the errors you pointed out.

Comment: Thanks. So what's the problem exactly now, your triangle is not appearing when (z < -1)? @bipolarpants

Comment: Ya, which for the life of me I can't figure out why the clipping space isn't being changed.

Comment: Huh, now when I multiply by my projection matrix nothing displays regardless of the Z. So I guess I've been pointed the problem? Though nothing seems to fix it.